# Vuetify: Automatic treeshaking in Nuxt.js

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js, tree-shaking

I'm trying to get the automatic tree-shaking functionality provided by the Nuxt.js / Vuetify module working. In my nuxt.config.js I have:

```
buildModules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', {treeShake: true}]
],
```

However, I'm only using one or two components at the moment, but I'm still getting a very large vendor.app (adding the treeshake option had no effect on size)

```
Hash: 9ab07d7e13cc875194be
Version: webpack 4.41.2
Time: 18845ms
Built at: 12/10/2019 11:04:48 AM
                         Asset       Size  Chunks                                Chunk Names
../server/client.manifest.json   12.2 KiB          [emitted]                     
       5384010d9cdd9c2188ab.js    155 KiB       1  [emitted] [immutable]         commons.app
       706a50a7b04fc7741c9f.js   2.35 KiB       4  [emitted] [immutable]         runtime
       8d5a3837a62a2930b94f.js   34.7 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]         app
       9d5a4d22f4d1df95d7a7.js   1.95 KiB       3  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/login
                      LICENSES  389 bytes          [emitted]                     
       a0699603e56c5e67b811.js    170 KiB       6  [emitted] [immutable]         vendors.pages/login
       b1019b7a0578a5af9559.js    265 KiB       5  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  vendors.app
       b327d22dbda68a34a081.js   3.04 KiB       2  [emitted] [immutable]         pages/index
 + 1 hidden asset
Entrypoint app = 706a50a7b04fc7741c9f.js 5384010d9cdd9c2188ab.js b1019b7a0578a5af9559.js 8d5a3837a62a2930b94f.js

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  b1019b7a0578a5af9559.js (265 KiB)
ℹ Generating pages                                                                                               11:04:48
✔ Generated /                                                                                                    11:04:48
✔ Generated /login
```

Notice the line indicating the large vendors.app

`Notice: b1019b7a0578a5af9559.js    265 KiB       5  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  vendors.app`

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***My mistake, the above configuration is working correctly. The real issue is the file size of the CSS being included (for all components) included in the build.***

For people suffering from the same problem, adding `build: {analyze:true}` to `nuxt.config.js` shows where the problem files are (automatically opens in a browser window when running `npm run build`).

[image: Results of webpack analysis]

Clearly main.sass is the issue here. I will ask the question of how to get Nuxt/Webpack to only use CSS modules for relevant components in another question. The article [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte#required-styles) only shows how to do it with the CLI, not Nuxt.

**Edit:** I've now added the `extractCSS:true` property to my Nuxt config and the file size is reduced to a few kb..

```
build: {
    analyze:true,
    extractCSS: true
}
```

Comment: when u say few kb is it around 277.24kb?